# Defining concrete types for a generic component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am typing to build an input component which is basically a `select` for enums in my app, and then define them for the concrete types in a series of one-liners. But whatever I try I seem to hit typing issues. The closest I've got is this:

```
import React from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  enumType: T;
  value?: keyof T;
};

type IEnumInput<T = {}> = React.FC<Props<T>>;

const EnumInput: IEnumInput = ({ enumType, value }) => {
  const options = Object.values(enumType).map((x: any) => x.toString());

  return (
    <div>
      Will select from {options.join(',')}, current value is {value}
    </div>
  );
};

type CProps<T> = {
  value?: keyof T;
};

enum MyEnum {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c',
}

const MyEnumInput = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<CProps<MyEnum>>) =>
  EnumInput({ ...props, enumType: MyEnum });
```

The error I get is

```
   Type '{ enumType: typeof MyEnum; value?: number | "big" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | ... 35 more ... | undefined; children?: React.ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Props<{}>'.     Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
       Type 'number | "big" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | ... 32 more ... | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
         Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Is this the right approach, and if so, what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;

Use `typeof MyEnum` in place of `MyEnum`.

Long answer:

You confuse enum as a value with enum as a type.

When you access `MyEnum.A` you use it as a value, which in transpiled js is a plain object, then access its property '.A'.

When you refer to `MyEnum` as a type, you’re actually referring to the value part of that key-value struct, which in your case is string literal `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`.

If you want to get the type of the plain object `MyEnum`, you need to use `typeof MyEnum`.

As a side note, the same thing happens to class in TS.

When declare `class Dog {}`, `Dog` is both a type and a value.

When referring to `Dog` as a type, it’s the type of instance of this class. When referring to `Dog` as a value, it’s the `Dog` class itself, aka, the constructor function, not the instance.

Now if you want to get the type of `Dog` constructor function, you need to use `typeof Dog`.

Comment: Thanks. I assume you mean `const MyEnumInput = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<CProps<typeof MyEnum>>) =>
  EnumInput({ ...props, enumType: MyEnum });`? That works, but now I get a different error: 
`Types of property 'value' are incompatible.       Type '"A" | "B" | "C" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.         Type '"A"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`

Comment: It seems changing the type above to `type IEnumInput<T = any>` fixes is, althought I'm not entirely sure why.